# C++ - Find numbers between first and last negative numbers in Array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, iterator

I got the question about finding the summary of numbers in Array between first and last negative numbers, here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
float a[] = { 1.5, 55, 5, 4.4,7.1,9,8,2,4.2, -3, -3.2, 5.2, -9 };
float eq = 0;
float sumofnums = 0;

for (int g = 0; g < 13; g++) {

    if (a[g] < 0) {
        sumofnums = a[g];
        cout << sumofnums << endl;
    }
}
```

I want to find summary between first and last negative numbers, I tried the method: sumofnums+= a[g];  but the answer is -15.2 while actually it is -10.

Comment: you want the sum of those numbers? find the position of the first and last negative numbers then loop and sum

Comment: 1) You mean `sumofnums += a[g];` 2) `I want to find summary between first and last negative numbers` That translates to: `sum of negative numbers.`

Comment: Yeah, I tried and the answer isn't right...

Comment: The answer is -15.2   programme ignored  5.2

Comment: `Yeah, I tried and the answer isn't right.` You forgot to tell us the output and the expected output for a specific input.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. So in your example you want to sum `-3, -3.2, 5.2 and -9`? Please [edit] your question and confirm and/or clarify.

Comment: Yeah... but don't know how

Comment: @MichaelWalz Oh now I see what he means.

Comment: @user8141203 please [edit] your question and put clarifications there.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: -10 is the right answer for  (-3)+(-3.2)+5.2+(-9), but  the output is -15.2

Comment: @user8141203 find the index of first and last negative number: and then `for(i=begin; i<=end; i++) sum+= a[i];`

Comment: @user8141203 Use common logic: 1) Iterate array until you find the first negative number (store the index) 2) Iterate array in reverse until you find the first negative (store the index) 3) Iterate from index1 to index2 and sum them up.

Comment: You mean:

for(int g = 9; g < 13; g++) ??     No way to find it programically?

Comment: @user8141203 the code in your question doesn't sum anything. It should be `sumofnums += a[g];`, but this is still wrong because this code only sums the negative numbers, that's why you get -15.2 (= -3 - 3.2 - 9)

Comment: "No way to find it programically?" I just told you a way to find it programmatically.

Comment: @user8141203 how would you do it on paper?

Comment: Oh, I see, Thank You so much :*

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: _What do you mean?_ who are you talking to?

Comment: I asked you when you wrote "How would you do it on paper?"

Comment: Done! Thank you guys so much 

Comment: In other words : how would you do it "by hand", without computer?

Comment: @MichaelWalz  I'm doing it in computer, Why should I do it on paper?

Comment: @user8141203 because resolving the problem with a pencil and a piece of paper may help you to figure out how to write the program.

Comment: @MichaelWalz  Maybe it's better to work on computer to  run written program too, and try all possible methods

Comment: @user8141203 this method is called "trial and error". It may work, but it's definitely not the best method. Everybody here will agree.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Understandable, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  float a[] = { 1.5, 55, 5, 4.4,7.1,9,8,2,4.2, -3, -3.2, 5.2, -9 };
  float sumofnums = 0;

  int size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);  // size is 13 here, this allows you
                                        // to determine the size automatically
  int first = 0;
  int last = size - 1;

  for (int g = 0; g < size; g++) {
    if (a[g] < 0) {
      first = g;
      break;
    }     
  }

  for (int g = size - 1; g >= 0; g++) {
    if (a[g] < 0) {
      last = g;
      break;
    }
  }

  for (int g = first; g <= last; g++) {
    sumofnums += a[g];
  }

  cout << "Sum is " << sumofnums << endl;
}
```

It should be clear enough without comments.

Answer (score 0):

This loop

```
for (int g = 0; g < 13; g++) {

    if (a[g] < 0) {
        sumofnums = a[g];
        cout << sumofnums << endl;
    }
}
```

sequentially assigns negative values of the array to the variable `sumofnums` instead of accumulating all values in the required range.

If to use standard algorithms then the program can look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    float a[] = { 1.5, 55, 5, 4.4, 7.1, 9, 8, 2, 4.2, -3, -3.2, 5.2, -9 };
    float sumofnums = 0.0f;

    auto first = std::find_if(std::begin(a), std::end(a),
        std::bind2nd(std::less<float>(), 0.0f));

    if (first != std::end(a))
    {
        auto last = std::find_if(std::rbegin(a), std::rend(a),
            std::bind2nd(std::less<float>(), 0.0f)).base();

        sumofnums = std::accumulate(first, last, sumofnums);
    }

    std::cout << sumofnums << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
-10
```

If to use manually written loops then the program can look like

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float a[] = { 1.5, 55, 5, 4.4, 7.1, 9, 8, 2, 4.2, -3, -3.2, 5.2, -9 };
    const size_t N = sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a);
    float sumofnums = 0.0f;

    const float *first = a;

    while (not (first == a + N) and not (*first < 0.0f))
    {
        ++first;
    }

    if (first != a + N )
    {
        const float *last = a + N;

        while (not (last == a) and not (*(last - 1 ) < 0.0f))
        {
            --last;
        }

        for (; first != last; ++first) sumofnums += *first;
    }

    std::cout << sumofnums << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is the same as shown above.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Nobody knows this.:)